# Sizing HTML5 canvas to browser width

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, width

Not sure why I can't figure this out but I am trying to draw a rectangle using HTML5 canvas. The height is predefined. However i want the width to be 100% of the browser. I've been using code examples from here but nothing has worked so far.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
body { 
    background:#414141;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    display:block;
}

html {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
}

</style>
```

HTML & Javascript

```
<canvas id="navBar" style="display:block; width=100%"></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("navBar");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#262626";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,navBar.width,125);
</script>
```

instead of navbar.width I have tried screen.width and window.innerWidth neither one works. Any ideas or suggestions to do this better?

Answer (score 2):

Oops I put too many quotes here

```
<canvas id="navBar" style="display:block;" width="100%"></canvas>
```

should be

```
<canvas id="navBar" style="display:block; width=100%"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
c.style.width=window.innerWidth;
```

Of course, this has the problem that if the browser resizes the window, the canvas will either be too big or too small. So we can attach an event listener and wait for a resize like this:

```
c.style.width=window.innerWidth;

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    c.style.width=window.innerWidth;    
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your canvas to `<canvas id="navBar" style="width:100%"></canvas>`

Then just get the width of the `<canvas>` element.

```
var c = document.getElementById("navBar");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var width = c.width;

ctx.fillStyle = "#262626";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,125);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69L6jac8/)

Answer (score 0):

### Try:

```
c.width = screen.width;
```

### Explaination:

- `screen.width` is a global variable which stores the screens current width.
- This code sets the width property of the canvas (`c.width`) to that value.

Also note that there is another global variable, `screen.height` which stores the screens' current height. This can be set in a similar manner.